# How to disable removal of the letter "s" when importing a table in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

When I import a SQL table in "Visual Studio" through "Server Explorer" to "LINQ to SQL", the program automatically removes the letter "s" from the end of the table name and creates the class with a different name from the table .

Is there any setting in "Visual Studio" for me to disable this automatic removal?

Comment: I don't remember how the dialogs are but there should be an option to pluralize the names which is on by default.  If using the EF designer, you'll see the option in the properties of the generated context in the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable pluralization of names for O/R Designer. You can disable it in *Tools > Options > Database Tools > O/R Designer* settings:

[image: O/R Designer Settings]

Now when you'll drag some table from server explorer to design surface, name pluralization will be turned off and you'll get entity name equal to database table name.

Note: I don't recommend you to turn off pluralization, because entity names in plural form are confusing.